# Is there any reason not to use 'protected' properties?

Tags: c#, .net, protected

Just wondering...

Is there any reasons not to use protected properties?

I mean instead of using this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

to use this one:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar;

    protected Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    protected GetBar()
    {
        return _bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one is perfectly valid Java; so if you see C# code like that, the most likely reason is that it has been written by a Java programmer who hasn't really accommodated to C# yet.

Comment: You use `protected` for accessibility, it has nothing to with properties.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see any reason why you would use a `GetXXX()` method instead of a property regardless of it's modifiers.

Since you tagged this question with `C#` tag, I strictly recommend using the first approach. That is what properties are for.

Use a method only when value returned by it can be different every time you call it regardless of it's state. For example, `DateTime.Now` was a mistake and should have been a method.

For more details refer to Property [`Usage Guidelines on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28VS.71%29.aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1). On a side note, it's surprising how they haven't had a need to change it since `Framework 1.1`.

Comment: As mentioned above by ammoQ, this is probably either code ported from Java or a Java programmer's work - that's the standard in Java.

Comment: There is no requirement that a property should be idempotent. It should only be 'pure' with no side-effects.

Comment: @leppie: If you look at the guidelines, there is one in list when methods should be used that says `Calling the member twice in succession produces different results.`. Of course, it also mentions about having no side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

A few more reasons to use properties instead of methods:

- Data binding can only see properties
- You can use read only or write only semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have non-writable or non-readable Attributes inside the class

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really about `protected` it has more with: why should I use properties?

Propeties are logically equivalent with Getter/Setter method pairs, whatever you can do with a with a `Name {get{} \ set{}}` you can do with a `GetName() \ SetName()` pair and vice versa, especially as C# has getter and setter accessors, so we can play with the accessibility too.

But, there are some folks that feel that public (or protected) properties are a bit like cheating from an OOP perspective, especially if all that the property does is just expose a backing field. After all `person.Name = "SWeko"` seems like it changes the state of the object externally, while `person.SetName("SWeko")` merely tells the object that it needs to change it's state. And from a purely theoretic standpoint I think that those objections have merit.

However, not all of us have the luxury of living in ivory towers, so the concept of properties is really usefull, as it's more readable, less error prone, and IMHO, closer to the real world model. It also provides us with a kind of dichotomy, when i write something like this:

```
person.Name = "SWeko";
person.Work();
```

I expect that the first line will a fast assignment, and will not have side-effects, while I expect that the second line will do something more, and probably affect the inner state of the object. When I use Getter and Setter method, no such distiction is immediately obvious:

```
person.SetName("SWeko");
person.Work();
```

Comment: IMHO, read-write properties should behave like variables.  If an object implements some read-write properties, writing them and then reading them in any order without any intervening *method calls* should cause them to read back the values written.  I have no problem with writable properties changing the values of read-only properties, or with method calls changing the values of any or all properties (read-only or read-write), but I dislike inter-connected read-write read-write properties. IMHO, something like StringBuilder.Length should be a read-only property, paired with a SetLength method.

Comment: @supercat This would get very tedious working with UI controls, as they tend to have lots and lots of properties that depend on each-other in a expected and logical way (e.g. AutoSize affects Width and Height properties).

Comment: @SWeko: A paradigm which I think is missing from parts of Forms, and which would help improve its utility, is the separation of "settings" properties from "current behavior".  For example, "Visible" should be split into "RequestedVisibility" and "IsShown".  "RequestedVisibility" should be a read-write property that would always return the value written; "IsShown" should be a read-only property indicating whether the control and all its parents have RequestedVisibility set.  For sizing, there should be requested-size and actual-size properties, the former read-write the latter read-only.

Comment: @SWeko: It could certainly be useful to have methods to copy the current state of an object to the "requested" state, and to have a means of invoking such methods from within the UI editor; I can accept that absent such a feature one may have to do somewhat ugly things with properties to make the UI editor work nicely.  Defining things as much as possible in terms of orthogonal properties, however, will help to avoid problems when serializing and unserializing objects.

Comment: @Supercat: Again, in theory, that approach has merit, as it will be a cleaner design, but does not match the expected (and quite real) human woldview. Not to mention that it would take a ton of code just to show your form.

Comment: @SWeko: Obviously the .net Forms class is what it is, but I would suggest that when designing a new class one should avoid having read-write properties that don't behave as orthogonal variables.  That doesn't mean one must absolutely reject any design in which read-write properties interact, but such designs should only be used in cases where an alternative form with orthogonal read-write properties would be demonstrably inferior.  As for "the expected world view"...

Comment: @SWeko: ...I would think it much less confusing for a control to have a read-write "RequestedSize" property (which would be unaffected by things like MultiLine) and a read-only "DisplayedSize" property, than to have a single "Size" property whose setter writes "RequestedSize" and whose reader fetches "DisplayedSize".  With such designs, the internal state of a control when a control or form is saved won't be accurately recreated when it's reloaded.  Whose "world view" is that supposed to match?